# File Redirection Input inC

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that takes numbers from a separate .txt file and turns them into a factorial and then finds the amount of times each prime has occurred in the factorial.

I have been working on this code for the last few days and after many hours i keep getting stuck on the same thing, it will compile with no errors but when I try file redirection to get an input from another file it stops and acts like it is asking for input on an endless loop.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Storage_array[5];

int current_prime, next_prime, factorial, prime_count, prime_number, num, factorial_current, factorial_next_num, current_number, total_number; //various variables used in program

int find_prime_count(int factorial, int prime_number); //3 functions declared below main()
int find_next_prime(int factorial, int current_prime);
int is_prime(int num);

int a, b, c; //utility varbles

main() 
{
    if((a=scanf("%d", &c)) == EOF) //checks to see if file is empty
    {       
        return 0;
    }
    for(b=0; b<c; b++) 
    {
        if((a=scanf("%d", &c)) == EOF) //checks to see if reached end of the file
        {
            break;
        }
        scanf("%d", &Storage_array[b]); //paces values from file into the storage array
        printf("%d! = ", Storage_array[b]); //formatting the output
        for(c=0;c<5;c++)
        {
            if(c=0) //creating a base case
            {
                current_prime = 2;
            }
            else
            {           
                current_prime = next_prime; //updates the current prime after the base case
                next_prime = find_next_prime(Storage_array[b], current_prime); //performes the outside functions that fine the next                                                     prime number within the factorial
                prime_count = find_prime_count(Storage_array[b], current_prime); //performs outside function that finds the number                                                  of the current prime within the factorial
                printf("(%d^%d)",current_prime ,next_prime); //prints the results in proper format
            }

        }
        printf("\n"); //spaces between factorial numbers
    }
}

int is_prime(int num) //function that determines if the input number is a prime number or not
{
    for(a=2; a<num; a++) //base case knowing lowest prime is 2
    {
        if (num % a == 0) //determines if the number is a prime number using remainder when divided by various numbers
        {
            return a; //returns the number if it is prime
        }
    }
}




int find_prime_count (int factorial, int prime_number)
{
    for(a=0;a<factorial;a++)//tests all possible prime numbers under the input factorial
    {
        if(a=0) //base case for lowest possible prime in factorial
        {       
            factorial_current = 1;
            factorial_next_num = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            factorial_current = (a*factorial_next_num);
        }
        if(factorial_current % prime_number == 0) //determines if the prime number fits into current factorial number
        {
            current_number = (factorial_current/prime_number); //finds number of times prime number fits in
            total_number = (total_number + current_number); //adds total amount of times that prime has fit within the factorial
        } 
    }
    return total_number;
}

int find_next_prime (int factorial, int current_prime) //function that determines the next prime within the factorial
{
    for(a=current_prime;a<factorial;a++) //checks all possible primes within the factorial
    {
        if (factorial % current_prime == 0) //determines if the number is a prime number using remainder when divided by various numbers
        {
            return a; //returns the number if it is next prime
        }
    }
}
```

the text file i have has the following content and is called input.txt

```
7
67
9
43
0
```

Comment: first - it does not compile, second after fixing all errors and running it with your data it core dumps with division by zero at this line `if (factorial % current_prime == 0) //determines if the number is a prime number using remainder when divided by various numbers`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.